# Eclipse: No generator named "system-uuid" is defined in the persistence unit

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, persistence.xml

I have a maven enabled project imported into Eclipse. From Eclipse, I get an error "No generator named "system-uuid" is defined in the persistence unit" on the system-uuid portion of the following lines:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(length = 36)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

The project builds correctly from the command line. What is causing Eclipse to generate this error and how do I fix it?

The persistence file looks like this..

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="xxxx"/>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can turn the error off/down under Preferences -> Java Persistence -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings under 'Queries and Generators' by changing the error 'Generator is not defined in the persistence unit' to a warning.

This looks like a bug in the Hibernate Tools extension of Dali in Eclipse.You could report this to Hibernate Tools or maybe this is fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: But if the developers put this error to be checked, I'd stop to consider that we should do something in persistence.xml, don't you think so? :S

Comment: This answer seems quite old. I've just downloaded Eclipse luna and the problem is still there. I can't believe a bug would be live for such a long time. Is this really a bug on Dali?

Comment: This worked for me. However, I must agree with @IgnacioRubio. This suppresses the error and let's us proceed... however, why is the error being thrown in the first place? I have not found the solution based on my research.

Comment: 2018 and its still persists! Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers - 2018-09. I suggest to make changes to project specific settings. Under 'Errors/Warnings' click 'Configure Project Specific Settings' option and update.

Comment: Still up and not running in 2019, LOL

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse Luna: This seems to work

```
Project -> Clean
```

Answer (score 6):

Newer versions of Eclipse' JPA support seem to depend on the order of Annotations. You are defining the generator after you try to use em.

This will work:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@Column(length = 36)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

However the order of annotations in Java must not have a meaning. So Karen is right, it seems to be a bug.

Comment: Didn't work for me either in any order.  And Project > Clean... (suggested below) didn't help in either order.  I'm using Mars.2 (4.5.2).

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same error - I used my custom id generator - in eclipse mars after importing my project from github.

the error : 
**No generator named “idGenEchantillon” is defined in the persistence unit**

So my answer is not really for the main question, but for other developers having same error as mine which can see here.

the code :

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "idGenEchantillon", strategy = "com.labo.model.KeyGenaratorForEchantillon")
@GeneratedValue(generator ="idGenEchantillon")
@Column(name = "ID_ECHANTILLON", length = 12)
private String idEchantillon;
```

I used maven to manage dependencies.

1. I've removed the JPA facet from my project => every time I update my prject using Maven, the project take the JPA facet again => the error stay.
2. I've disabled "JPA Configurator" option of Maven : Window >> Preferences >> Maven >> Java EE Integration , then uncheck "JPA CONFIGURATOR", after that I've update my project using Maven => the error is gone.